# Xml class that can have a child class that is exactly the same

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I need to parse this xml document (portion only):

```
<channel>
 <item>
   <title>a</title>
   <description>aa</description>
   <link url= "www.a.com" />
 </item>
<item>
   <title>b</title>
   <description>bb</description>
   <link url= "www.b.com" />
 </item>
<item>
   <title>c</title>
   <description>cc</description>
   <link url= "www.c.com" />
 </item>
<item>
   <title>d</title>
   <description>dd</description>
    <channelContents>
      <item>
         <title>a</title>
         <description>aa</description>
         <link url= "www.a.com" />
      </item>
      <item>
         <title>b</title>
         <description>bb</description>
         <link url= "www.b.com" />
      </item>
      <item>
         <title>c</title>
         <description>cc</description>
         <link url= "www.c.com" />
      </item>
    </channelContents>
 </item>
</channel>
```

This is my code:

```
List<ItemList> itemList = null;
reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(content));
loadedData = XDocument.Load(reader);
var query = from i in loadedData.Descendants("item")
    select new ItemList
    {
        Title = (string)i.Element("title"),
        Description = (string)i.Element("description"),
        Link = (string)i.Element("link").Attribute("url").Value
    };
itemList = query.ToList();
```

I'm getting an error whenever I parse the Link. And I think I found out why, it is because of the tag `<channelContents>`. The item with title "d" has that tag which was present after the description in which, violated the pattern of the `<item>`. Is it possible to just parse the items in `<channelContents>` since it has the same item(a, b and c)?

I'm getting an error:

> NullReferenceException because itemList is null.

I tried removing `Link = (string)i.Element("link").Attribute("url").Value` and it did work. But I need to get the Link.

Comment: Always post the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError practices what he preaches.

Comment: I assume the lack of quotes around the `url` attributes is a typo?

Comment: i just forgot to include the quotes in my post here.

Comment: how many elements do you want to return?  Do you want to ignore the 4th item since it doesn't have a link?  Or have a null for the link value?

Comment: As this is closed, I [answered on gist here](https://gist.github.com/3152271).  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the fourth item doesn't have a immediate link node.

```
  var query = from i in loadedData.Descendants("item")
                        select new 
                        {
                            Title = (string)i.Element("title"),
                            Description = (string)i.Element("description"),
                            Link = (string)i.Descendants("link").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("url").Value
                        };
```

might do what you want.. return 7 nodes.. a,b,c,d and again another a,b,c

Comment: yes that is my problem, instead of the link node, i got another tag which is <channelContents>